# prepare sql conditionally

Tags: sql, informix

I am trying to prepare a sql query. I need to prepare Query1 if value val3 is not NULL and Query2 if value val3 is NULL. This is being tried in Informix ACE programs. I donot want to prepare two different select statements, but need to handle in 1 stattement.

Query1:

```
select tab1.col1
WHERE tab1.col2=val1
AND   tab1.col2=val2
AND   tab1.col3=val3
```

Query2:

```
select tab1.col1
WHERE tab1.col2=val1
AND   tab1.col2=val2
```

I tried 
Query3:

```
select tab1.col1
WHERE tab1.col2=val1
AND   tab1.col2=val2
CASE WHEN  val3 <> ''
THEN tab1.col2=val3
ELSE ' '
END
```

But case statement syntax doen't handle expression

Comment: I just noticed there may be a typo in your query, you have where 'tab1.col2=val1 and tab1.col2=val2', is this what you want?  the only way for this to be true is if 'val1 = val2'

Comment: Is `val3` an ACE variable or how is it set?  John Boker's answer (using an OR clause) seems logical, but if `val3` is an ACE variable, it might complicate things — I don't immediately recall whether you can directly test an ACE variable like that.

Answer (score 0):

So in essence you want to 
tab1.col3 to be = to val3 when provided otherwise you want tab1.col3 to be equal to itself; so it doesn't affect the results.  However if tab1.col3 is null; null equalities don't work so we have to set tab1.col3 to some value to make the equality work.

```
SELECT  tab1.col1
WHERE tab1.col2=val1
  AND tab1.col2=val2
  AND coalesce(tab1.col3,-1) =  case val3 when null then coalesce(tab1.col3,-1) else val3 end
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like

```
select tab1.col1
WHERE tab1.col2=val1
AND   tab1.col2=val2
AND   (tab1.col3=val3 or val3 is null)
```